# how to make a div with divs added by javascript completely scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, yui

I have a div `report_container` which is used to display a collection of dynamically generated charts. the charts are drawn using javascript (Yahoo UI library) and they are plotted on divs which are created dynamically using javascript as well ( because the number of charts varies) when I set`report_container` styles overflow to scroll, the div scrolls but the charts which were drawn does not scroll at all. Any idea how can I make the charts scroll with the rest of the content?

EDIT: a screenshot from the console .. the highlighted div is the one where one of the charts start and is created by YUI

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to your problem. I'm guessing it has something to do with the css of those charts if the Yahoo UI library has one but we can't be sure without seeing your code

Comment: im working on a local copy .. YUI has its own javascript and css files

Comment: @Caelea i added a screenshot .. sorry about the size .. u need to save it to view it properly

Comment: n this case the container div (of what you've highlighted) should have `position:relative`

Comment: hmm .. i tried changing while in the console and it works .. but this div is dynamically generated by YUI .. how can I override its position?

Comment: Yes, put in your css file or with inline style your position and add `!important` at the end (before `;`). It will override everything.